# Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested

Tags: amazon-s3, policy

I have uploaded image from one domain into the bucket and when i am trying to access the uploaded image from other domain than i am getting the following issue randomly not always:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. s3 bucket

Below code I have written into the CROS policy of s3 bucket

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
     <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
     <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
     <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    </CORSConfiguration>
```